# Overloading subscript operator causes access violation

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I get an access violation error when I use a self written Buffer class:

```
template<typename T> 
class Buffer {
public:
    Buffer(T *data, size_t len);
    Buffer(size_t len);

    size_t len();

    operator T*();
    T& operator[] (const int x) const {
        return this->data[x];
    };

private:
    T *data;
    size_t _len;
};

int main() {
    Buffer<char> b("123", 3);
    b[0] = 0; // This line causes "Access violation writing location 0x003c8830".

    return 0;
}
```

Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Removed `[c]` tag, this is clearly C++. Next, we won't know how that happened until we see the constructors, but I have a vague idea...

Comment: String literals are read only, guessing the constructor just points to the string passed in. Can you post the constructor definitions?

Comment: you should allocate memory for `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that causes the issue is not in the post, but it's very likely your constructor: if you assign the pointer `data` to the member `data`, then you store the string constant inside your class. Then code of the `main` than tries to write into non-writable memory, causing access violation.

You can fix your constructor to avoid this problem:

```
Buffer(T *dataIn, size_t len) {
    data = new T[len];
    memcpy(data, dataIn, len*sizeof(T));
}
```

Comment: Hey, don't go stealing my mystical glass orb of psychic debugging! ;)

Answer (score 1):

`"123"` is a string literal stored in read only memory,
When you do:

```
b[0] = 0
```

You are trying to write to the read only memory thus invoking **Undefined Behavior**.

You need to allocate dynamic memory to `data` so that it ***owns the memory*** and your code then modify's the owned memory and not the non writable memory which it does not own.
Also, Do make sure You follow the **[Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)**.

Comment: Congrats on the Legendary badge!

Answer (score 1):

String literals such as "123" are non-writeable. You attempt to assign a value to it when you do b[0] = 0;

In addition, string literals have a terminating NULL character, making that 4 long.

You can specialize you constructor to copy const char inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the definition of the constructor, but I bet you're using the assignment operator to copy the C string to `Buffer::data`. You instead need to use `strcpy()`. Also, you'll need to allocate 3 + 1 bytes for `Buffer::data` to ensure that you have enough room for the nul terminator.